# Пунктуация во фразе "язык что одежда"

Tags: пунктуация

Почему во фразе "язык что одежда" запятая не ставится?

Answer (score 5):

> Почему в фразе "язык что одежда" запятая не ставится?

В этом предложении *"что одежда"* -- **сказуемое**.

[См.:](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=656#pp656)

> **§ 90.** Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) ***как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что*** не выделяются запятыми в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> <...>
>
> в) если оборот является сказуемым: ...***Ручей по весне что река***.